# Div that varies in length

Tags: css, html

I am making a site with several image galleries.  Above these galleries is a description of each collection.  However, because each description varies in length, I need the  to vary in size to fit the content, and the  to vary to accommodate the "collection" div.  I don't even know where to start.

Comment: HTML flows content dynamically by default.  The `div` will, by default, increase its size to enclose its content.  Is there more to the story that you haven't shared?  Or at least some code which demonstrates the problem you're seeing?

Comment: If you look at my answer, it should give you the result you need.

Comment: the issue is that my site isn't acting in line with everything i've learned.  if i don't give my divs 'margin-top' properties, they display on top of one another;  if I close my "div id="gallery" tag, it displays incorrectly; the "collection" div moves slightly to the left or right depending on the page. And i've combed and combed and can't find what is making my site act this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/aZKjC/1/

Is this what you want?

Code:

```
<div class="gallery">
    <div class="desc">
        Aliquam et nisl vel ligula consectetuer suscipit. Morbi euismod enim eget neque. Donec sagittis massa. Vestibulum quis augue sit amet ipsum laoreet pretium. 
    </div>
    <img src="" width="300" height="300"/>
</div>
```

Use CSS and float left with multiple divs with the `gallery` class for columns side by side with different heights.

Comment: this is what i'm doing. http://jsfiddle.net/alyssahelen/hyfxv/

Comment: What do you want it to look like?

Comment: Is this ok? I changed a few things. http://jsfiddle.net/hyfxv/1/

Comment: perfect! can i just copy and paste the css?

Comment: actually now, it all displays on top of my header and drop down menu.

Comment: i added margins, but now the 'collection' div doesn't line up with the gallery, even though they have the same margin-left value

Comment: jsfiddle so I can see?

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this

```
 .yourDiv{
 min-height:200px; 
 }
```

Just apply that class to all of the divs that need to be the same height just make the min-height bigger then your tallest div.

Answer (score 0):

**tag** is just a container, that you can put there whatever you want that is HTML.
The benefites of using  **tag** is that you can choose it an "id" to it, and than control it.
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_div.asp
How to control  **tag** - same as other elements. By css & some javascript :
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_height.asp

**div - you can write this way, i.e:**

```
<div id="id_mydivtest">&nbsp;</div>
...
<script>
document.getElementById("id_divtest").height = 300;
</script>
```

You should take a tutorial at http://www.w3schools.com

Good luck.

Comment: You should edit this to be a class not an ID because an ID should only be used on a single element it looks like they want this for a few elements.

Comment: the issue that I'm having is that the gallery won't move down to make room for the description.  for some reason, it lays right on top of it.